# Logging the current executing command within the Action Block for Set-PSBreakpoint

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am attaching a command breakpoint for every "Get*" in my powershell session. This command breakpoint involves calling an Action which invokes Write-Host "We are trapped in this code". As you can see below

Eg.

```
PS /Users/test> Set-PSBreakpoint -Command "Get*"  -Action {
>> Write-Host "We are trapped in this code"
>> }

  ID Script                                                   Line Command                                                  Variable                                                 Action
  -- ------                                                   ---- -------                                                  --------                                                 ------
   1                                                               Get*                                                                                                              …

PS /Users/test> Get-Runspace
We are trapped in this code

 Id Name            ComputerName    Type          State         Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ----          -----         ------------
  1 Runspace1       localhost       Local         Opened        Busy

PS /Users/test>
```

Now instead of printing

`We are trapped in this code`

we want to print

`We are trapped in this code: Get-Runspace`

In this specifically we want to print the command ie. **Get-Runspace** on which breakpoint was applied.
Is there any way to get the hold of the Executing Command within the ScriptBlock.

**PS:** *We have tried **$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name** within the script block and various other methods but all of them return null.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're interested in the *command line* that triggered the breakpoint, use `$MyInvocation.Line`:

```
Set-PSBreakpoint -Command "Get-conten*"  -Action { 
  Write-Host "We are trapped in this code: $($MyInvocation.Line)"
}
```

---

If you want to inspect the specific values of the automatic `$MyInvocation` variable (which is an instance of type [`System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo)), pipe it to the [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) cmdlet:

```
Set-PSBreakpoint -Command "Get-conten*"  -Action { 
  $MyInvocation | Out-Host
}
```